# Unsubscribe to old questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications

Stackoverflow from the beginning seemed to understand I don't want spam and doesn't email me. But after a few years my notification feed is filling up with 90% legacy notifications, spam by another channel.

In a nice world, I could turn off notifications about:

1. upvotes on old questions - This isn't actionable information. I'm flattered, but after six years, I don't care.
2. downvotes and close votes - I'd like to turn these off separately because they affect reputation.
3. answers on accepted question (I wanted an answer, not a life long job of curating the "best" answer)
4. comments on old questions with accepted answers - I don't work there anymore, that system was shut down, I don't even remember how to write COBOL, much less continue a 6 year old conversation about it.

The notification system abuses attention of users that have been with SO since the start.

Facebook allows unsubscribing, most blog allow for unsubscribing to notifications & comments, heck, even LISTSERV had an unsubscribe feature.

I looked at the UI closely, AFAIK, this isn't a feature that exists at the moment.

Comment: One thing that will grant all of that is disassociation. But that also negates all the reputation ever gained/lost on the post.

Comment: You mean community-wiki it?

Comment: @MatthewMartin No, when he says disassociation, he means disassociation.

Comment: No, I mean to detach the post from your account. As if it never belonged to you in the first place. It's one of the rights given by CC, though SE makes it very difficult to exercise that right. (probably for reasons related accountability and people trying to get around question bans?)

Comment: They are working on making disassociation easier. Lost the link for it though.

Comment: Disassociation appears to require contacting a live human at stack overflow. I don't care if my name is associated with the question, in fact, I enjoy the notoriety. I just don't want the notification spam after 6 years. Contacting a live human at SO for each question isn't an interesting solution.

Comment: Agreed. It would be nice to be able to customize what kinds of events I'm notified of.

Comment: It being a good idea to allow opting out of upvote-notifications on old content wholesale is certainly undisputable. Wholesale opting out of notification of new answers, comments, downvotes, revisions (and maybe closing), that's more problematic: Are you absolutely sure it cannot ever be interesting/informative/useful, nor need a reaction to avoid being mis-represented? Anyway, if you are completely dis-interested in those old posts, then self-service dis-association seems the answer, not turning deaf. Especially as there's a certain psychological inhibition to correct any *active* user's post

Comment: If the rest of the world wants a disassociation feature, let them have it, I hope they enjoy it. I just want to turn off the noise from my comment feed explicitly. Everyone else already *implicitly* ignores the content of posts they have psychologically stopped caring about, disassociated or not.

Comment: Agree with 1 but disagree with the rest. 2 is bad because DV/CVs are critical feedback for askers; I assume you personally don't need that, but many people do and allowing them to turn it off would be bad. 3/4 are bad because you own of the question - even though your initial problem was solved, you should feel responsible for curating the post, e.g. reporting bad late answers (spam, low quality, etc), or changing the accepted answer if the old one is outdated and there is a better way to solve the problem now. If you "enjoy the notoriety", then you should enjoy this responsibility as well.

Comment: I often go take a glance at an old answer when it gets an upvote, and probably find something to do with it 3/4 of the time, even if it's just flagging a 3-year-old "Thanks!" comment. That said, I agree that this should be customizable.